# JComboBox populates every time it is clicked

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to populate a `JComboBox` with data from a database which I have managed to do. The problem is, it populates every time an entry is selected. How do I solve this, I need it to populate once.

```
public void writeSku() {

   try{
       Class.forName(dbClass);
       connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
       state = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
       String query2 = "SELECT sku FROM drugs";
       result = state.executeQuery(query2);
       ResultSetMetaData meta = (ResultSetMetaData) result.getMetaData();
       int columns = meta.getColumnCount();
       while(result.next()){
              for(int i =1; i<=columns; i++){
              String skuValue = result.getString(i);
              skuCombo4.addItem(skuValue);
              }
       }
   } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error"+ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please make you code [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). We don't know what method you use to populate your `JComboBox` which is important to answer your question.

Comment: Am using the method described here "writeSku()".  i need to know what am doing wrong in the above method.@UwePlonus

Comment: If the while loop that fills your combo box is getting run multiple times, that suggests that writeSku() is getting called multiple times.  We cannot tell how without knowing about the code that calls it.  This is why you are encouraged to boil your problem down to a self-contained example and post it, to illustrate what your problem is.  A lot of times, you will discover your own answers (and learn other things) in the process of doing so.

Comment: i am calling it in the combobox's actionperformed  `private void   skuCombo3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        writeSku();
       
    }`